# Git issue with problematic file-name (#Makefile#)

Tags: git, filenames

So I got a code from a co-worker and cleaned it up.
One of the files that were relics of the past was #Makefile# (exact name).
I wanted to clean it up in the next commit, like many other unnecessary files. However, this one specifically causes trouble - it refuses to be deleted from the remote repository.

git status yields:

```
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    #Makefile#
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Any way I try to push this change to the remote repository doesn't do anything. I have tried git reset, checkout, pull, clean and so on to either clean it up or get the repository version and try again. In either case nothing works.
In the remote repository file remains unchanged...
[image: #Makefile# in remote repository]
(I'll point out that I can commit and push all other changes, this just sticks in the status bar)
I am sure it has everything to do with the file name - though I'm not sure how it got the name in the first place.
Any idea how to handle this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file name is not the issue. You just deleted the file without using `git rm`, hence you did not create a commit.

You need to actually delete the file from git and then commit:

```
git rm '#Makefile#'
git commit
```

(On most shells, quoting, i.e. `''` is needed around `#Makefile#` to avoid considering it as a comment, which are "`#` and everything that follows" in the bash family)

Then you will be able to push this commit.

Comment: it's the ' ' the changed everything :)